# SSIS package canceled for no obvious reason

Tags: sql-server, memory, ssis, agent

When I run my SSIS package in Visual Studio it executes just fine. However when I try to execute this same package using the SQL server agent, by either CmdExec or SSIS package type, it gets canceled. The package is stored on the IS catalog. All on the same server.

The standard report tells me task x failed, but is not showing any error messages. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the task itself as after an DB restore and rerun of the same package with the same data, a different task fails.

I have tried this several times and it always fails because of 1 (out of possible 3) task which are more or less close to each other in the control flow. Moreover the task that fails is only calling a stored procedure, which is completely encapsulated with try-catch.

The standard report is however throwing the following message at the time the package failed:

```
< ?xml version"1.0"?> < DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage xmlns: DTS=www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DTS"> 
< DTS:Peakworkingsetsize>320692224< /DTS.................
```

which makes me think it has something to do with memory. However can't find anything usefull on google about this message.

I already trying things for a week now but not able to find the solution. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

It might something going on in your tasks. I have noticed the same behavior while running SSAS cube. If it fails, gives not specific error. Try to disable all tasks and enable them one by one in order to find which contains the problem.

Comment: Hi Rafal, thanks for your answer. Tried that more or less. It will simply cancel because of another task. Also all s.p. tasks that failed were re-written with with try-catch, after which they failed again.